# Why can't selenium find a button in a Chrome Extension (Python)

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-chrome, selenium

I am using BeautifulSoup with Selenium.  I'm opening a webpage with Selenium with a chrome extension.  When I manually right click and 'inspect' on a button I can see the html

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 150px;">Find Email</button>`

If I right click and 'view page source' this html doesn't show up in the source code which I presume is why selenium cannot find it.  It seems to be driven by json and javascript but I am not sure on the full workings.  Can anyone suggest how I use selenium in this environment.

Here's how I'm opening the browser:

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_extension('/home/henry/Downloads/candidate.ai-get-email,-salary,-social-link_v0.3.6.crx')
    with closing(Chrome(chrome_options=options)) as driver:
        driver.get(url)
```

Here's how I'm trying to get the button:

```
    button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('btn')
    button.click()
```

Here's the error I'm given:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"btn"}
```

Comment: Your selector is not valid. A valid one would be: `button.btn`

Comment: Same error: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button.btn"}`

Answer (score 1):

As `btn` is not an element, but a `class` name, you cannot use it in your way. Some of possible ways you can use class name are:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn')
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn')
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn.btn-primary')
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="btn btn-primary"]')
...
```

Also you can find yor button by it's link text:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[.="Find Email"]')
button = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Find Email")
```

As your button located inside an `iframe`, use following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.switch_to_frame("bconsole")
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Find Email")))
...
# Perform required actions inside iframe
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Comment: You seem to know eactly what I'm trying to do but using  `button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[.="Find Email"]')` I get the following `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified`

Comment: And `button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[class="btn btn-primary"]')` gives `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button[class="btn btn-primary"]"}`

Comment: @HenryM, oh, sorry, `css selector` seem to be not so flexible as `XPath`. Please, check updated answer

Comment: If exception still exists, you might need to use `Explicit wait` to wait until your button appeared

Comment: Still no luck.  These are the errors and I've put in time-sleep(5) to ensure the page is loaded and I'm watching it load so I know it is all there.  `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class="btn btn-primary"]"}`  and `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[.="Find Email"]"}`

Comment: ok. Check whether your button located inside an `iframe/frame`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127896/discussion-between-henrym-and-andersson).

Comment: Still getting the same error after switching to iframe.  `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Find Email"}
`

Comment: That's created a different and interesting error because the message in blank: `File "linkedin.py", line 94, in <module>
    button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Find Email")))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: `

Comment: Yeah, it means that `webdriver` was waiting for 2 seconds, but element not appeared... it's too bad... Could you try to replace `By.LINK_TEXT, "Find Email"` to `By.XPATH, '//button[.="Find Email"]'`?

Comment: That has worked because it is nor erroring on the next line which is says is not clickable.  `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (1381, 317)`

Comment: Ok... Is there any `<a>` elements bind to this button? There should be a link on which you actually have to click

Comment: The is no <a> element within the section which is why I think it is running a javascript or jquery but I cannot find it

Comment: @Andersson FYI `By.LINK_TEXT` or `find_element_by_link_text` only works with `<a>` element innerText to locate while desire element is a `<button>` , don't provide wrong information to OP. Thanks